# Editable admin custom billing fields error issue in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have an error located in this code (that adds in order edit pages editable custom billing fields):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'order_admin_custom_fields' );
function order_admin_custom_fields( $fields ) {
    global $theorder;

    $fields['billing_address_3'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Home', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'=> get_post_meta( $theorder->get_id(), 'Home', true ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    $fields['billing_address_4'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Entrance', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'=> get_post_meta( $theorder->get_id(), 'Entrance', true ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    $fields['billing_address_5'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Floor', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'=> get_post_meta( $theorder->get_id(), 'Floor', true ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

The guilty line: `'value'=> get_post_meta( $theorder->get_id(), 'Home', true ),`

Report on the error:

```
example.com [Wed Jul 04 02:36:28 2018] [error] [pid 148187] sapi_apache2.c(362): [client 37.146.123.6:33708] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null in /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php:607\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): order_admin_custom_fields(Array)\n#1 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)\n#2 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php(87): apply_filters('woocommerce_adm...', Array)\n#3 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php(526): WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::init_address_fields()\n#4 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::save(951, Object(WP_Post))\n#5 /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#6 /home/c/cb360 in /home/c/cb36070/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php on line 607
```

But I need to get the saved values for those custom billing fields.

How can I solve this error issue, and get the custom billing field values?

The added (saved) meta data is made with this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Home', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Entrance', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Floor', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) );
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `$theorder` is not defined and you can't use `get_id()` method on it.

But the main problem in your code comes from your checkout billing fields first. They should be set, displayed and saved as follow *(taking a particular care of the `meta_keys` to be used when data is saved)*:

```
// Frontend: Display the custom billing fields (in checkout and my account)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' ,'add_custom_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function add_custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing_address_3'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Home', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Fill in your Home', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $fields['billing_address_4'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Entrance', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Fill in your Entrance', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $fields['billing_address_5'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Floor', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Fill in your Floor', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Save the custom billing fields (once order is placed)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_billingt_fields', 20, 2 );
function save_custom_billingt_fields( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_3', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_address_3', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_3'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_4', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_address_4', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_4'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_5', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_address_5', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_5'] ) );
    }
}
```

> You will see that those custom fields are also in My account > addresses > Edit billing address. And everything related is auto sync. No need of additional validation or saving code...

Now in admin order pages, for `woocommerce_admin_billing_fields` admin hook, the `'value'` key doesn't exist in the field array **and it is the guilty**.

As you have correctly set and saved your custom checkout fields, you don't need any `'value'` array key, as the data will be **auto populated**, if it exist. So your code will be:

```
// Backend: Display editable custom billing fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'order_admin_custom_fields' );
function order_admin_custom_fields( $fields ) {
    global $the_order;

    $fields['address_3'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Home', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    $fields['address_4'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Entrance', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    $fields['address_5'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Floor', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'  => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        'style' => '',
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> The error is now definitively gone

Comment: Thank you very much, Loic! I appreciate your help!